# Cannot resolve symbol FabricMySQLDriver

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I have a maven project where I added the mysql connector dependancy

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

It can see com.mysql.jdbc but when I import com.mysql.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver it cannot resolve the FabricMySQLDriver. I tried different version too, that people were using as examples when implementing this, but it's still missing. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the fabrics are all stored in com.mysql.jdbc.fabric, which the lastest version doesn't have, so I had to download an older one and change the path.

Comment: yes it works well with, for instance, 5.1.38 version